# React Native function return before fetching data could be done

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, async-await, fetch-api

I am simply trying to fetch a list of customers from the database and display it on the frontend. But for some reason the function keeps returning before the fetching could be done. However, when I try to console.log out the list it shows that it has been fetched. I used async/await but it still doesn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MTXA.png)

this is my entire code. I tested it by simply displaying one email address from the list and it showed this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzxQ2.png)

When I remove the line to display the email and console.log the whole list before returning the function, it shows that the whole list has been fetched in the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRH86.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuovC.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Posting screenshots is not recommended; it's usually _easier_ to just copy and paste your code, and much easier for the community. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75012490/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `AC_data` is null at the first render.

So in your return of you component instead of doing :

```
<Text>{AC_data[0]['email_address']}</Text>
```

You can do :

```
<Text>{AC_data?.[0]?.['email_address']}</Text>
```

Or you can set a loading while there is no data.